# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateutil' but Requirement already satisfied

Tags: python

When I run my program, I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateutil'
```

When I try to install dateutil with pip3, I get this message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Users/tommcginty/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from python-dateutil) (1.14.0)
```

I have tried unintstalling/reinstalling dateutil, but I keep getting the same message.
My code simply has these import statements:

```
import sqlite3
import urllib.error
import re
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from dateutil import parser
```

pip3 list shows:

```
Package           Version
----------------- -------
astroid           2.3.3
isort             4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy 1.4.3
mccabe            0.6.1
pip               21.0.1
pylint            2.4.4
python-dateutil   2.8.1
setuptools        49.2.0
six               1.14.0
wheel             0.34.2
wrapt             1.11.2
```

I'm using MacOS Big Sur.
Not sure if it makes a difference, but I'm on an M1 MacBook Air.
Thanks

Comment: could you see the results of `which pip3` and `which python` and compare their folders?

Comment: I get /usr/local/bin/pip3 for which pip3 and /usr/local/bin/python3 for which python3.

Comment: Can you paste the exact command you are using to run your program and the output you are getting

Comment: Note: `pip3 list` doesn't show beautifulsoup, so your bs4 import should actually be the one failing for what you've shown, so you're not using the correct Python interpreter. You need to start debugging with `python3 your_script.py` and `python3 -m pip list`

Answer (score 0):

I updated python to 3.9 and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue and found that

> pip list

> pip3 list

returned different installed modules

To fix this: I went through and installed the missing modules in pip3

> pip3 install MODULE_NAME